# Create a SimpleImage on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image

I tried to create an `SimpleImage` using JavaScript. But it gives me a console error as

> Uncaught ReferenceError: SimpleImage is not defined

I am unsure where the issue is coming from with the code below:

```
<script>
var img = new SimpleImage(200, 200);
for (var p of img.values()){
    x = p.getX();
    y = p.getY();
    w = img.getWidth()
    if (x > y){
    p.setRed(255);
    }
    if (x + y > w)
    {
        p.setRed(255);
    }
    if (x > 20){
        p.setRed(255);
    }
   }
print (img);
</script>
```

Comment: By SimpleImage you mean the library? If so, check if you're importing it correctly. Also, the SimpleImage constructor needs a Canvas and not width/height.

Comment: I want to create a simple image using javascript.. How to include a library to my script?

Comment: Please elaborate. What do you mean by "simple image"?

Comment: I'm following this code here https://sites.google.com/site/tech23repo/scripting/javascript

Comment: @RajindPamoda, imo this site is for the trash bin. Because the code doesn't work without a library AND they don't mention what library they use AND the one library I found doesn't provide the functions they use. So I don't know how to make their code work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you first need to include a library that contains SimpleImage() function, JavaScript doesn't include a predefined library like the one you mention. In the webpage you are looking for (sites.google.com/site/tech23repo/scripting/javascript), it also doesn't show which library you should be including in your script. So for example, for this to work:

```
<script>
   var img = new SimpleImage(200, 200);
   for (var p of img.values()){
       x = p.getX();
       y = p.getY();
       w = img.getWidth()
       if (x > y){
           p.setRed(255);
       }
       if (x + y > w){ //Indent this correctly
           p.setRed(255);
       }
       if (x > 20){
           p.setRed(255);
       }
   }
   print (img);
</script>
```

You need to have defined the method SimpleImage() somewhere, something like this:

```
<script async="" src="https://www.dukelearntoprogram.com/course1/common/js/image/SimpleImage.js"></script>
<script>
    //Rest of the code using SimpleImage() method goes here.
   var img = new SimpleImage(200, 200);
   for (var p of img.values()){
       x = p.getX();
       y = p.getY();
       w = img.getWidth()
       if (x > y){
           p.setRed(255);
       }
       if (x + y > w){ //Indent this correctly
           p.setRed(255);
       }
       if (x > 20){
           p.setRed(255);
       }
   }
   print (img);
</script>
```

Comment: I want to implement image stenography solution using JavaScript. Is there any tutorials that I can follow?

Comment: Something like this might work? https://github.com/zeruniverse/CryptoStego  or maybe try https://github.com/petereigenschink/steganography.js/ trying to use the same approach I gave in the answer above? Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The library you require is from the Duke / Coursera course you can obtain it here.
http://www.dukelearntoprogram.com/course1/common/js/cs101/SimpleImage.js

You can find more info here http://www.dukelearntoprogram.com/course1/

Comment: I'm following this code here https://sites.google.com/site/tech23repo/scripting/javascript

Comment: The library you require is from the Duke / Coursera course you can obtain it here.
http://www.dukelearntoprogram.com/course1/common/js/cs101/SimpleImage.js
You can find more info here http://www.dukelearntoprogram.com/course1/

Answer (score -1):

You require the library of DLTP(Duke University CourseEra Course).You can Inject it into your code offline or by online.
Online Injection of **SimpleImage** library:

```js
<script src="https://www.dukelearntoprogram.com/course1/common/js/image/SimpleImage.js" >
```

Offline Injection of **SimpleImage** library download link[DLTP Library Download Link]::https://www.dukelearntoprogram.com//downloads/archives/cs101.zip