# Changing Pixel Color using Javascript For Loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, colors, pixel

How can I change a 200x200 black image to yellow using Javascript For Loop?

What I know is that black is (0,0,0) and yellow is (255,255,0)

```
var img = new SimpleImage(200,200);
print(img);

for (var pixel of img.values()){
pixel.setRed(r);
pixel.setGreen(g);
pixel.setBlue(b);
}
```

Comment: replace r and g with 255 and b with 0

Comment: @KavianRabbani, how can I do this? Can you help me please? Thanks!

Comment: just type them :) (like @nylki 's answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48445833/5626568

Answer (score 2):

As @Kavian said, you would need to replace the variables (r,g,b) with the values you want. (Or alternatively define the variables beforehand). This should do the trick:

```
var img = new SimpleImage(200,200);
print(img);

for (var pixel of img.values()){
    pixel.setRed(255);
    pixel.setGreen(255);
    pixel.setBlue(0); 
}
```

What the code does, is to go through each pixel of the image iteratively and simply set every pixel to (255,255,0) which is yellow.

Also the last line in the loop `pixel.setBlue(0);` could be omitted if you are sure that all pixels are completely black to begin with. The above code is failsafe in that regard, as it makes sure that the pixels are yellow, regardless of the previous color value.

Comment: If you start with a completely black image, wouldn't setting the "blue" value of each pixel to zero just keep things as they are, leaving the image black? (because the rgb values of a black pixel are already all zeroes)

Comment: @RobertLozyniak of course you are right. I'll correct the answer. I accidentally swapped 0 with 255 in my head for black.

Answer (score 1):

You`ll have to print the image after you change the pixel colors.

var img = new SimpleImage(200,200);

```
for (var pixel of img.values()){
    pixel.setRed(255);
    pixel.setGreen(255);
    pixel.setBlue(0); 
}
print(img);
```